# Meaning of "Base" in Walsh Hadamard Tranform in Image Processing?

Tags: image-processing

Currently, I am studying a paper by *K. He and J. Sun, “Computing nearest-neighbor ﬁelds via propagation-assisted KD-trees,” in Proc. IEEE Conf. Comput. Vis. Pattern Recog., 2012, pp. 111–118.*

In the paper there is a sentence which i can quote as:

> ...  We use the ﬁrst 16 WHT **bases** for the Y channel2 and 4 for each
>   chrominance channel (Cb/Cr) throughout this paper. ...

Although I have made a search on the internet, I couldn't get the meaning of **base**.

In MATLAB 2014b There is a function `fwht(x,n)` where `n` is the order of the transform. Can this **order** be the **base** that i am trying to find the meaning of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that here *bases* stands for "basis vectors". From the cited paper by  Y. Hel-Or and H. Hel-Or. [Real time pattern matching using projection kernels](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0684/acef32c9f750961045908c54521485512330.pdf), 2003, ICCV,  you can see the set of $8 \times 8$ vectors from  a separable Walsh-Hadamard basis:

[20] Y. Hel-Or and H. Hel-Or. Real time pattern matching using
projection kernels. In ICCV, pages 1430–1445, 2003.

It consists in a tensor product of two $8$ 1D Walsh-Hadamard transforms (one horizontal, one vertical).

[image: Walsh Hadamard basis]

The sixteen 2D vectors  in the left-top $4\times 4$ square are the one with the lowest sequencies (**sequency** is the  frequency analog for [Walsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_matrix)-Paley-Hadamard transforms), in terms of "maximum sequency":

[image: first 2D Walsh Hadamard basis vectors]

Comment: Thank you for your response, i think this will help me quite a lot to find myself a better understading of the concept.

Comment: One small question though, after having a glance at the paper that was posted, and the one I have quoted from, in which the sentence continues as 
"Thus we represent each patch by a 24-d vector."
I couldn't catch the mathmetical relationship between the **order, base**, and **dimension** of the W-H matrix.

Comment: 24 probably comes from 16 coefficients from the Y (luminance) channel and two times 4 for each chrominance channel : $16+4+4=24$.

Comment: Indeed, so it can be simplified as: **1 base** = **1 dimension**  = **lg2(1) orders**, do you believe this is correct?

Comment: To get a $8\times 8$ FWT, you will apply  'fwht' with order $8$ on both the columns and rows of a  $8\times 8$ image patch.

Comment: Did further research and found out that, for an **N** x **N** image, the order is **lg2(N)**. Thus for an **8** x **8** image the order is **3**.

_Credits to Prof. Sen Gupta, IIT KGP._

Comment: I am not sure about what is meant by order here. In 'fwht(x,n)', 'n' is length of the basis vectors, and should be a power of two. From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardMatrix.html, for Hadamard matrices, order is the length, while for Walsh sequences of order 'n', they have a '2^n'  length